# Zebra ZPL cut off trailing instead of wrapping

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl

I am correcting a ZPL string which is overlapping text. Here is that string.

```
^XA\r\n
^CF0,31,24\r\n
^FO25,20^FDMFD BY:^FS\r\n
^FO25,20^FB412,2,5,L,0^FDMFD BY: THE LONGNAME MANUFACTURING COMPANY     
LONGNAME, IL^FS\r\n
^XZ
```

Pluggin that into http://labelary.com/viewer.html you will see that on the second line of text, the words overlap each other. This can be fixed by allowing the text to wrap onto a third line, but I am limited to only 2 lines of text.

Instead of trying to wrap over the second line, how I can cut off the excess letters?

In other words, I want it to render as if the text looked like this.

```
^XA\r\n
^CF0,31,24\r\n
^FO25,20^FDMFD BY:^FS\r\n
^FO25,20^FB412,2,5,L,0^FDMFD BY: THE LONGNAME MANUFACTURING COMPANY     LONGNA^FS\r\n
^XZ
```

This way it does not try to wrap the third line, but limits it to only 2 lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `^TB` instead.  It has the cropping you are looking for:

```
^XA
^CF0,31,24
^FO25,20^FDMFD BY:^FS
^FO25,20^TBN,412,62^FDMFD BY: THE LONGNAME MANUFACTURING COMPANY LONGNAME, IL^FS
^XZ
```

Answer (score 0):

I would update the program which is the source of the data to only pull X number of characters, and if more exist, add "..." to the end of the string. That way the audience of the label knows something is being truncated.